# A Boundary value problem involving the Laplacian [Help to proceed]

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, mathematical-modeling, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

I have the equation $(1)$ defined on $x \in [0,L]$ and $y \in [0,d]$

$$
<\nabla^2-\beta><\mathcal{D}>T_2(x,y)+\alpha\beta T_2(x,y)=-\alpha m\gamma \frac{\cosh(m(d-y))}{\sinh(md)}  \tag 1
$$
where $$<\mathcal{D}>=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \alpha$$ and $$<\nabla^2-\beta>=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-\beta$$
 governed by the boundary conditions
$$
\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} \vert_{x=0} = \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} \vert_{x=L} = \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial y} \vert_{y=d} =  \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial y} \vert_{y=0}=0 \tag 2
$$
Also the following is known
$$
<\nabla^2-\beta>T_2 (0,y)=0 \tag 3
$$

How should I approach to solve $(1)$ ?

Trying an ansatz like $
T_2(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k(x)\cos(\frac{k\pi y}{d}) \tag 9
$ over-complicates thing. Can there be any other approach ?

---